# iOS UI Test: How can I check an appointment in the calendar?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm running an UI test with Xcode using XCTest on an iPad. The actions in this Test result in setting an appointment in the standard calendar app of iOS. The date will always be the same as the date the test is running.

Is there a way to check in the same test-function, if the date was correctly set in the calendar app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Xcode 9 you can now access other apps in your UITests. So to test if an event was correctly added to the Calender you can write a simple test:

(I use a small demo app for this. It only has a button "Add Event" that adds an event on the current day from 5 AM to 7AM)

```
import XCTest

class CalendarUITestDemoUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    }

    func testIfEventIsAddedToCalendar() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let calendarApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilecal")

        app.launch()

        // add event
        app.buttons["Add Event"].tap()

        // check if event is in calendar
        calendarApp.launch()
        let event = calendarApp.buttons["Demo Event, from 5:00 AM to 7:00 AM"]
        XCTAssert(event.exists)

        // delete event
        event.tap()
        calendarApp.toolbars.buttons["Delete Event"].tap()
        calendarApp.sheets.buttons["Delete Event"].tap()
    }
}
```